# Testing for presence of form instance in Jinja2

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2, wtforms

I'm using WTforms with Jinja2 and want to change my templates page title depending on whether I am creating a new instance of editing an existing form object.

This is what I wrote in the template:

```
{% block title %}{% if form.obj %}Edit{% else %}New{% endif %} Post{% endblock %}
```

What I expect to see:

if the form is filled out I expect to see "Edit Post" in the page title.

if the form is empty I expect to see "New Post" in the page title.

What I get:  "New Post" in both instances.

Here is my PostHandler that is passing the form values.

```
def with_post(fun):
    def decorate(self, post_id=None):
        post = None
        if post_id:
            post = models.BlogPost.get_by_id(int(post_id))
            if not post:
                self.error(404)
                return
        fun(self, post)
    return decorate

class PostHandler(BaseHandler):
    def render_form(self, form):
        self.render_to_response("edit.html", {'form': form})

    @with_post
    def get(self, post):
        self.render_form(MyForm(obj=post))

    @with_post
    def post(self, post):
        form = MyForm(formdata=self.request.POST, obj=post)
        if post and form.validate():
            form.populate_obj(post)
            post.put()
            post.publish()
            self.render_to_response("published.html", {'post': post})
        elif self.request.POST and form.validate():
            post = models.BlogPost()
            post.title = form.title.data
            post.body = form.body.data
            post.tags = form.tags.data
            post.publish()
            self.render_to_response("published.html", {'post': post})
        else:
            self.render_to_response('edit.html', {'form':form})
```

In short, all I'm trying to do is test whether the form is filled, and change my page title "New Post" or "Edit Post" accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Form accepts a obj argument, it doesn't actually store it, it just uses that obj to fill in any blanks that formdata didn't provide.   So when you ask Jinja2 `{% if form.obj %}` it's always going to be False, because there is never a obj property (unless you have a field that happens to be called obj of course).

If you're editing a post, you'll have an id to work with so you know which post to update in the database, so where are you currently storing that?  Assuming you store it as a hidden field, you could just do:

```
{% if form.id.data == None %}Must be a New form {% endif %}
```

If you wanted to check if the entire form was empty, you could access the `form.data` dictionary, and make sure all the entries are `None`, although you need to be careful, because I know that FileField returns a `u'None'` instead of a real `None`, so you'd have to double check what Fields you care about.